# Do we need NIC to ping loopback IP

Tags: networking, network-adapter, loopback

I read that pinging loopback will work if we have TCP/IP suite installed on our computers and don't necessarily have a NIC. So, do we need NIC to ping loopback ip(127.0.0.0) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Quoted from this answer http://forums.pcper.com/showthread.php?336976-Can-you-ping-127-0-0-1-if-your-NIC-card-is-burned-out

> Actually 127.0.0.1 is just the loopback address for TCP/IP protocol stack. It let's you know you have the protocol installed and windows is recognizing it. Has nothing directly to do with a NIC, as you can still do this test with a generic modem in a system without LAN network hardware or access.
>
> Loopback address is a special IP number (127.0.0.1) that is designated
> for the software loopback interface of a machine. The loopback
> interface has no hardware associated with it, and it is not physically
> connected to a network. The loopback interface allows IT professionals
> to test IP software without worrying about broken or corrupted drivers
> or hardware.

So that means you do not need a NIC to be able to ping your loopback addresses.

Comment: So that's actually a "No", isn't it? Or at least "Yes, but not necessarily a physical one..."

Comment: @grawity Yes you are right. I forgot to change the Yes to a No. Loopback address is not associated with both physical or virtual nics.